# Different linux OS on particular hdd

Tags: centos, grub2, dual-boot, grub

Have Adaptec RAID controller. There're 4 hdds on it. 
Existed Centos 5.10 on:
/dev/sda1 - /boot ext3
/dev/sda2 - LVM

I decided to migrate to Centos 7 and installed It on:
/dev/sdd1 - /boot XFS
/dev/sdd2 - LVM

So...As far As I can't choose disk boot priority due to RAID, How can I point BIOS to boot mbr from /dev/sdd (Centos 7).

Also we need to keep in mind that Centos 5 - Grub 0.9 and Centos 7 served by Grub2.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that during the installation of Centos 7, you installed Grub 2 on the MBR of /dev/sdd, you will have to enter BIOS and then you will chose your Hard Disk Drive that corresponds to `/dev/sdd` (like demonstrated [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=bios%20first%20boot%20device&espv=2&biw=864&bih=931&source=lnms&tbm=isch&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ei=_hBMVfaBEYXY7Abk0YOYDw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgrc=bFwv_N2efKLjnM%253A%3B55TJiHBKEV9OCM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fcached.avoiderrors2.netdna-cdn.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F03%252FChange-First-Boot-Device-in-BIOS-to-Boot-From-CDDVD.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.avoiderrors.net%252Fchange-first-boot-device-in-bios%252F%3B500%3B315)).

Different grub versions will not be a problem, since you will only use one of them. :)